# Blazor RenderFragment to String

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a code block component using `.Net 6 Blazor wasm`. I need to display the `RenderFragment` as `string` and also render the component in my html.

Here is my code block component,

```
<pre class="language-html">
    <code class="language-html">
        @("Some way to get non rendered html from @ChildContent")
    </code>
</pre>

@ChildContent

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the above component as,

```
<CodeBlock>
    <Chat></Chat>
</CodeBlock>
```

**Expected Output:**

```html
<Chat></Chat> 
<!-- This is the input I passed inside as RenderFragment and I need the exact Render Fragement Code; 
not the Rendered Html code of the RenderFragment -->
```

[image: Chat Component]

Component gets rendered as expected. But unable to get non rendered html of my `RenderFragment`

One option is to pass the `RenderFragment` content as string parameter to `CodeBlock` component. But this results in duplicate and non readable `HTML`. Also this becomes difficult to maintain when the `ChildContent` has multiple lines of code.

```
<CodeBlock Html="@("<Chat></Chat>")">
    <Chat></Chat>
</CodeBlock>
```

Any hints/suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: No. The link you shared is about returning static prerendered HTML in blazor server side. I need non rendered HTML of `RenderFragment`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, not possible without pulling a lot of code out the DotNetCore repo and building a parallel Renderer to produce the emitted HTML.

Comment: Theoretically, you could invoke the RenderFragment with your own instance of a RenderTreeBuilder, then inspect the Frames and re-contruct a version of the original markup, but you'd be on your own doing that.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a tough question. From what I understand you want to be able to render the `ChildContent` of your component but also be able to view the `ChildContent` data as plaintext razor code, or HTML if that's what's in your `ChildContent`, right?

So an option would be to surround your `@ChildContent` renderer tag with a `<div>` and assign that div a unique id when the parent component is initialized. Then you create another variable, let's call it `private string RawContent { get; set; }`. Then write a javascript function that takes an id value and gets the element by id from the DOM and returns the element's `innerHTML`.

I created a test project to try it and it works. Here are the snippets that are relevant.

In your `Component.razor` file:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
<pre class="language-html">
    <code class="language-html">
        @RawContent
    </code>
</pre>

<div id="@ElementId">
    @ChildContent
</div>
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    private ElementReference DivItem { get; set; }
    private string RawContent { get; set; }
    private Guid ElementId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        base.OnInitializedAsync();

        RawContent = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("GetElementHtmlText", ElementId.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then in your `index.html` file add this in side of a `<script>` tag, or to one of your javascript files:

```
async function GetElementHtmlText(elementID) {
            await setTimeout(() => {  }, 1);
            console.log(elementID);
            var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
            console.log(element);
            var result = element.innerHTML;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
```

Then anywhere you wish to use this component you will render the HTML markup and have the Raw Text available as well. However this function will return all of the html markup raw text, meaning that you get the razor tags and the empty comment elements that Blazor inserts as well (ie. `<!--!-->`). But as long as you know that you can work around them.

I didn't do this but you could modify this to call the JSInterop function inside the `RawContent`'s getter instead of just when the component initializes.

Comment: InnerHTML will return the rendered HTML. But I want non rendered HTML(Razor/Blazor) tags. `<InputText>` as `RenderFragment` should render the component and also the HTML markup should be same `<InputText>` not the rendered `<input type='text' />`

Comment: @fingers10 I have the same need.  I literally want to get the markup that went into the RenderFragment.  Any ideas since this post?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I ended up using GitHub gist. You can find the source code from https://ilovedotnet.org github repo. You can also consider https://github.com/erossini/BlazorCodeSnippet or https://sciencevikinglabs.com/blog/development/2021-01-02-blazor-code-snippet-highlightjs/ or https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/blazor/add-code-snippet-in-razor-pages/