# Blazor RenderFragment is never null

Tags: c#, null, components, blazor

I'm pretty new to Blazor and I came across this problem when trying to make a generic tooltip component I can wrap around any content.  Consider the following component:

```
@if (TooltipContents != null) 
{
    <div class="tooltip_container">
        <div class="tooltip_body">
            @TooltipContents
        </div>
        @Item
    </div>
}
else
{
    @Item
}

@code
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? TooltipContents { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? Item { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is TooltipContents is never evaluating to null and I think this is because I am doing this:

```
<Tooltip>
    <TooltipContents><MyTooltipContentComponent/></TooltipContents>
    <Item>Test Item</Item>
</Tooltip>
```

Now even if MyTooltipContentComponent returns no content at all the RenderFragment is never null and I end up with an empty tooltip on hovering over my item.  Only some of the items in my list of data will have tooltips but the tooltips themselves are quite complex which is why I wanted to make them into components.  Is there another or better way to do this?  There seems to be no way to find out if a RenderFragment is empty but not null.

Comment: You could maybe: add a Parameter in `MyTooltipContentComponent` telling if it has some content, bind it to a bool variable in the parent and also assign this variable to a bool parameter in `TooltipContents`.

Comment: Maybe this could be your chance, but ehh.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685102/blazor-renderfragment-to-string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand what a `RenderFragment` is.  It's a delegate.  if no method (that matches the pattern) is assigned to the field/property then it's null.  If a method is assigned, then it's not null.  The method may not do anything, but the owner of the delegate cannot determine that.

So:

```cs
<TooltipContents><MyTooltipContentComponent/></TooltipContents>
```

contains a method (created by the Razor Compiler) that creates a component with no content.  `ToolTip` only knows it's not null, the fact that it doesn't produce any content is irrelevant.

If you don't want a tooltip to appear, don't assign anything to `TooltipContents`: it's declared as nullable (with ?).